# Minimize tons of codes ( Toasting )

Tags: android, eclipse, toast

i have a bunch of toasting codes which makes my project file crowded. Does anyone know how to lessen it by using an abstract class? heres my block of codes of my toast

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_example1,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);   
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
```

thank you. And I hope this question can help future developers.

**UPDATE** here's my work

```
public abstract class Utility {

public static void makeToast(Context context, int s, int layoutId)
{
    try
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    //  TextView text = (TextView) layoutId.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(s);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.setView(view);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("UTIL", "Caught exception while attempting to create 
              alertdialog");
        ex.printStackTrace();
```

I have a difficulty on how will I set textview text so that I can use a bunch of toast in a single layout

Comment: What would be the advantage of the abstraction?

Comment: I can minimize my codes in doing methods there. also it help to save more layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.demo.R;

public class CustomToast extends LinearLayout {
private Toast toast;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomToast(Context context) {
    super(context);
    toast = new Toast(getContext());
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


public void displayToast(String message){

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_linear_toast));
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_toast_message);
    text.setText(message);

    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
}

public void cancelToast(){
    toast.cancel();
}
}
```

Layout file : custom_toast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_linear_toast"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@color/light_red">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_toast_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Custom Toast"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Call this class and its methods and show/cancel toast when it required.

Comment: how can i change the parameter of the method into a `int` because I want to use R.string.

Comment: change text.setText(s) to text.setText(context.getString(s));, also intialize Textview, otherwise it throws error.

Answer (score -1):

```
Call this toast method and pass the parameters to display the toast.

void toast(int layoutname,int layoutid,int gravity){
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(layoutname,
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(layoutid));
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(gravity, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);   
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
}
```